# Php,Sql search function giving out all data instead of relevant queried data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, search

im stuck proper on this one. i have a web app with all my company's information ie. Staff information, i have it all displayed but what i want is for the front end user to be able to search the database with a name ie. bob. I have that done, like i have made the connection but when i type a name into the box and hit search it just returns all the staff details.

Heres my code:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <title>searchable</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/index_stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>

    <?php
        $form = "<html>
        <h1>Search By Name</h1>
        <form method=\"get\">
          <label>Name:
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"keyname\" />
          </label>
          <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Search\" />
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>";

        //capture search term and remove spaces at its both ends if there is any

        if(!empty($_GET['keyname'])){
            $keyname = $_GET['keyname'];

            $searchTerm = trim($keyname);

            //database connection info
            $host = "localhost"; //server
            $db = "development_suite"; //database name
            $user = "root"; //dabases user name
            $pwd = "";//password

            //connecting to server and creating link to database
            $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

            //MYSQL search statement
            $query = "SELECT  firstname ,surname,address,mobile,email
                        FROM development_suite.eeg_staff;";

            $results = mysqli_query($link, $query);

            /* check whethere there were matching records in the table
            by counting the number of results returned */
            if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1){
                $output = "";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
                {
                    $output .= "firstname: " . $row['firstname'] . "<br />";
                    $output .= "surname: "  . $row['surname'] . "<br />";
                    $output .= "address: " . $row['address'] . "<br />";
                    $output .= "mobile: " . $row['mobile'] . "<br /><br />";
                    $output .= "email: " . $row['email'] . "<br /><br />";
                 }
            }else{
                $output = "There was no matching record for the name " .
                strip_tags($searchTerm);
            }

        } else {
            $output = "Please enter a Name.";
        }
            echo "$form\n$output";

        ?>
</body>
```

Comment: You should learn about the `WHERE` clause of the [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) statement.

Comment: You don't have a WHERE clause in your query.

Comment: your query has no `WHERE` clause to filter results, of course it will return all results. You'll need to pass the `POST`ed search terms to the query. (preferably using a prepared statement)

Comment: And you'll probably need to learn about [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Okay thank you people, yes im relatively new to php...Thanks though:)

Comment: you even declared $searchTerm already... so would be also great to use it in your query :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem I think in your query it is missing the where clause:

replace the line

```
$query = "SELECT  firstname ,surname,address,mobile,email
                        FROM development_suite.eeg_staff;";
```

with this line

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$searchTerm);
        $query = "SELECT  firstname ,surname,address,mobile,email
                                FROM development_suite.eeg_staff 
WHERE firstname LIKE '%$search%' OR surname LIKE '%$search%'";
```

What the above query does is make search on two fields firstname and surname based on the search key you provided.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You do not just stuff things like `$searchTerm` into your query when using `mysqli`. That just created a gigantic [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). All you need to do is add a placeholder `?` and use `bind_param` with the %-ified string.

Answer (score -1):

you must be use the where condition in select query to select specific records do change in select query

```
$query = "SELECT  firstname ,surname,address,mobile,email
                        FROM development_suite.eeg_staff where firstname='".$searchTerm."' ";
```

or use like this

```
$query = "SELECT  firstname ,surname,address,mobile,email
                        FROM development_suite.eeg_staff where firstname  like %'".$searchTerm."'% ";
```

thank you

Comment: This is using `mysqli`, so it should be using placeholders.